# Problems loading model; Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to load a model I saved with the following and it gives me this error:

```
import torch

model = torch.load('./grunet.pkl')
model.eval()
```

This is the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\eval.py", line 4, in <module>
    model.eval()
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

Please help!

Comment: Please post relevant information regarding your system (Python version, PyTorch version, OS). Also,

Comment: Make sure that the weights file exists in the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one step:

```
model = YourModelClass()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("./grunet.pkl"))
model.eval()

# do something with the model
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. As a follow up to this, I now get the following error:

`model = GRUNet(input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, n_layers)`
`model = torch.load('.//GRU//GRU_1028_48.pkl')`
`model.eval()`
`model.predict()`

`AttributeError: 'GRUNet' object has no attribute 'predict'`

Comment: There is no such thing as ```predict()```in pytorch. What are you trying to do?

Comment: So I ended up realizing that you have to do model(inputs) to do an inference. The problem I now have is is that the error in predictions is far off from what training or evaluation loss are showing.

Comment: Yes. I'll just make a new post.